# Splitting up data from MySQL from a single table

Tags: mysql

I have this very old and crappy table:

```
meetingid_bigint  key              field_prompt     data_string
1                 meeting_name     Meeting Name     Introduction
1                 location_text    Location Place   Main Office
1                 location_street  Street Address   Street number 1
1                 location_town    Location Town    Town
1                 time_start       Start Time       10.00 AM
2                 meeting_name     Meeting Name     Follow Up
2                 location_text    Location Place   Office
2                 location_street  Street Address   Street number 2
2                 location_town    Location Town    Town 2
2                 time_start       Start Time       1.00 PM
3                 meeting_name     Meeting Name     Introduction
3                 location_text    Location Place   Main Office
3                 location_street  Street Address   Street number 1
3                 location_town    Location Town    Town
3                 time_start       Start Time       8.00 AM
```

And so on with about 4000 records. As you can see same meeting occurs over and over with a new number. I want to break out the different `meeting_name`, `location_text`, `location_street` and `time_start` data from `data_string` so I can put this in separate tables and use FK's instead. This table is crazy. So the question is, how do I get all the meetings with the same name and place in a query for extraction? The only difference is the time. The meeting name always follows the town and address.

Output:

```
MeetingName      Location     Town      Address 
Introduction     Main Office  Town 1    Street number 1  
Follow Up        Office       Town 2    Street number 2
```

Something like that.

**Edit**

Thank you Barranka, it somewhat helped.

But now I get this output:

```
meetingid_bigint    MeetingName    Location     Town    Address
1                   Introduction
1                                  Main Office
1                                               Town 1
1                                                      
2                   Follow Up
2                                  Office             
2                                                Town 2  
2                                                       Street Number 2
3                                                       Street Number 1
3
3
3                                                Town 1
```

Tried to change to `group by 'MeetingName'`, then I get it almost as I wanted with all the MeetingNames in nicly order and no dublets, but nothing in Location, Town or Address.

```
select meetingid_bigint
    , case `key` when 'meeting_name' then data_string end as MeetingName
    , case `key` when 'location_name' then data_string end as Location
    , case `key` when 'location_street' then data_string end as Address
from main_meeting_table
group by MeetingName, Town
```

That code gives me both the MeetingName and Town, but first all of the Names, then all of the Towns. It's correct `meetingid_bigint`so question is, can I join those two somehow?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want.  If you want to put the values in one row, this is called a pivot.  You can google "MySQL pivot" for ways to accomplish this.

Comment: That data structure is actually not so bad IF each meeting may have a variable number of attributes associated with it, especially since you seem to be having different value associates with each attribute (key, field prompt, data string).  This is actually a pretty common way of storing these sorts configuration relationships in a relational database.  Now if you find you are always only having 5 properties for each meeting, then a table structure like you propose may make sense.  IN this case, I would think you would have 16 fields (id plus 3 * 5 fields for properties).

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes I know, but there are some other aspects to why I need to break it up as well. And yes, this sort of structure works if you have people maintaining the database and are familiar with it. Problem is that that isn't the case and there are also other tables involved. So in this case I have to do queries on several tables on same values and join. My idea is to break it down to as few queries as possible and also easier for non sql people to at least understand it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're in for a lot of pain.</strike> You need to create a "pivot" query.

MySQL does not provide a built-in instruction to build pivot queries, but you can build one by hand:

```
select meeting_id
     , case `key` when 'meeting_name' then data_string end as MeetingName
     , case `key` when 'location_name' then data_string end as Location
     , case `key` when 'location_street' then data_string end as Address
     -- And so on
from your_table
group by meeting_id;
```

Hope this helps.

**Little comment:** Avoid using reserved keywords (such as `key`) as column names